# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I tried to make Android Project

I have

```
OS Windwows 10,
Intellige IDEA 2017.2
JDK jdk1.8.0_161
Android API 27 Platform
Gradle 4.6
Android SDK 25.5.2
```

Installed packages

[image]

[image]

[image]

create Emulator

[image]

settings SDK

[image]

tried make project

[image]

returned error

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Server/Repositories/projects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a>
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: That dependency is from https://maven.google.com. You will need to add that as an artifact repository for use by IDEA. I do not use IDEA much personally, and so I do not know the details of how to do that.

Comment: What is the name of the package need to add?

Comment: Um, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, preferably with a concrete version number (e.g., `27.1.0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the google maven to your root build.gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

For Gradle build tools plugin version 3.0.0, you can use google() repository (more at Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0

> **Important**: The support libraries are now available through Google's
>   Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository
>   from the SDK Manager. For more information, see [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html).

Another option (check CommonsWare comment): [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353457/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727#comment85707433_49353457)